# UnicodeEncodeError when using pandas method to_sql on a dataframe with unicode column names

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

This is my first time posting on stack overflow, so bear with me. I have been scouring the internet for an entire day and I have not been able to fix this problem.

Basically, I have a Pandas DataFrame with unicode characters in the column names, and I am getting a UnicodeEncodeError when I try to use to_sql to store the data in a database. I can reproduce the error with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns = [u'\xe9',u'b'])
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:pass@localhost/testdb')
df.to_sql('data', engine, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)
```

The last line of the traceback looks like this:

```
C:\Users\isaac_000\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.pyc in _get_column_names_and_types(self, dtype_mapper)
857              dtype_mapper(self.frame.iloc[:, i]),
858              False)
--> 859             for i in range(len(self.frame.columns))
860             ]
861 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would appreciate any help you guys can provide. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thanks joris, that seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: Hex `e9` is not Unicode (or UTF-8).  In `latin1` it is `é`; perhaps that is what you wanted?  But failed to establish that the client was encoded in latin1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the current `to_sql` method, and I filed it here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11431 (and will probably be fixed in version 0.17.1)

As a workaround, I would suggest to

- remove the special unicode character for now in the column names
- or patch your pandas installation (the fix is very simple and small, see here what you should have to change: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11432)